# root cannot access user's home folder shared via NFS

Tags: ldap, nfs, file-permissions, root

We have a local server that exports an `NFS` share, used as parent directory for Linux home folders in the network. The users authenticate via `LDAP` (running on the same server).

Authentication works fine, and the home folders on the share also work well for the users after they have logged in to a client machine.

However, there is one problem: the root user on the client cannot access the user folders. That is a problem as even simple things such as `sudo apt-get` produce errors because root cannot write to the user's folder.

I thought the problem might be that the home folder permissions on the `NFS` server are 0700, thus only accessible by the user itself. So I have changed this permission to 0770, also also set the group ownership of the user folder on the server to 0, i.e. root. I assumed this should work, as 0 is also root's group ID on the client machines.

Unfortunately, that didn't solved my issues, root still cannot access the user's folder:

```
root@Mule:/home/users# ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 team      team  4096 Aug 20 14:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root  4096 Oct 29 10:43 ../
drwxrwx--- 30 mfb       root  4096 Jan 30 17:49 mfb/
root@Mule:/home/users# 
root@Mule:/home/users# cd mfb
bash: cd: mfb: Permission denied
root@Mule:/home/users# 
root@Mule:/home/users# ll mfb
ls: cannot open directory mfb: Permission denied
root@Mule:/home/users# 
root@Mule:/home/users# whoami
root
root@Mule:/home/users# 
root@Mule:/home/users# mount | grep users
bison:/media/profiles on /home/users type nfs (rw,hard,intr,addr=192.168.0.2)
root@Mule:/home/users#
```

I am out of ideas here. Any suggestions how I can enable root to access the user home folder on the client (`mfb` in this example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the *exports* man page:

> Very often, it is not desirable that the root user on a client machine
>   is also treated as root when accessing files on the NFS server. To
>   this end, uid 0 is normally mapped to a different id: the so-called
>   anonymous or nobody uid. This mode of operation (called 'root
>   squashing') is the default, and can be turned off with no_root_squash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `no_root_squash` on the export. Otherwise, accesses by the root user are mapped to an anonymous user (usually nobody).

Answer (score 1):

you need to check how the NFS mount is being exported.  Likely "root_squash" is enabled.

From Docs:
root_squash — Prevents root users connected remotely from having root privileges and assigns them the user ID for the user nfsnobody.

no_root_squash option turns off root squashing

More info here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html